# Python giving different answers for integration in different environment

Tags: python, scipy, precision, numerical-integration

Hi I am trying to integrate the following function,

> ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> ∫<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> 1/B(-log x, -log y) dx dy

using

```
scipy.integrate.dblquad(lambda y,x: 1/ scipy.special.beta(-math.log(x),-math.log(y) ), 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1)
```

in Ipython 3.5 Spyder IDE, where B() is the Beta function. I get 6.81... with accuracy of 10<sup>-6</sup>. But on Linux when I run the same piece of code with Python 2.7 I get the correct answer of 2.05 (verified with Mathematica). I am confused. Whats happening?

**Edit**

I posted this question in [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/26168/numerical-double-integration-with-endpoint-singularity-in-scipy-python-gives-inc) where I was recommended to post it in here. I am using Windows 10, Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit), scipy version 0.18.1, for which I get the incorrect answers. Is someone able to reproduce them?

Comment: I am sorry you received bad advice, but it looks like your question will likely get migrated to the correct site. Regarding the math markup: that is enabled on a site-by-site basis, and Software Engineering does not have it.

Comment: thanks for migrating the question and making edits!

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using in each case?  (You can check by running `import scipy` and looking at `scipy.__version__`.)

Comment: Running python 2.7.11 and scipy 0.17.0 I obtain `(2.0505570600455982, 1.4380486579312901e-08)`; cannot test 3.5 atm.

Comment: @Warren, both are using scipy `0.18.1` . In windows its Python `3.5` and in Ubuntu I am using python `2.7.12` In Anaconda Spyder though I get the following warning, `IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.' which might be one of the reasons I get a wrong answer. But I dont understand why same version of scipy library gives a warning in one and none in the other. I tried it in a friends laptop with Spyder (same version of scipy and python) and got same warning with wrong answer. I am wondering if anyone get the same warning and wrong answer with Ipython?